# How to pack a Libary control in a jar

Tags: jsf, xpages

I've built some library controls in Java to extend some (JSF) controls like Edit Box, Combobox and so on. I would like to pack my controls (only the java code) in a JAR file, but everytime I replace the java files with my jar I get an error.

Does someone have an idea why I get this error? I can't create a plugin because the extended controls should only be available in one NSF.

> Error 500
>   HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception

Here is the full error from the logfile:

```xml
<CommonBaseEvent creationTime="2012-11-22T12:28:27.960+01:00" globalInstanceId="ELc0a8643600013b27e0473d00000000" msg="CLFAD0131E: Unable to push data because: Could not open the document" severity="50" version="1.0.1">
    <extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:level" type="noValue">
        <children name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:name" type="string"> 
            <values>SCHWERWIEGEND</values>
        </children>
    </extendedDataElements>
    <extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:sourceClassName" type="string">
        <values>com.ibm.commons.log.AbstractLogMgr</values>
    </extendedDataElements>
    <extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:sourceMethodName" type="string">
        <values>log</values>
    </extendedDataElements>
    <extendedDataElements name="CommonBaseEventLogRecord:Exception" type="string">
        <values>com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Could not open the document&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.doOpenDocument(DominoDocumentData.java:505)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDocumentDataSource.openDocument(AbstractDocumentDataSource.java:148)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDocumentDataSource.load(AbstractDocumentDataSource.java:100)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDataSource.getDataContainer(AbstractDataSource.java:474)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.getDataObject(DominoDocumentData.java:146)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDataSource.pushData(AbstractDataSource.java:576)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.util.DataPublisher.publishControlData(DataPublisher.java:181)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.publishControlData(UIDataPanelBase.java:310)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.initBeforeContents(UIDataPanelBase.java:451)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.</values>
        <values>initBeforePageContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:668)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:339)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.addComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:389)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.buildContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:453)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildFacet(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:205)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.component.UICallback.buildContents(UICallback.java:180)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;a</values>
        <values>t com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.layout.UIVarPublisherBase.buildContents(UIVarPublisherBase.java:97)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.buildPageContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:692)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:340)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.addComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:389)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeCo</values>
        <values>mposite.buildContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:453)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.buildContents(UIViewRootEx.java:1649)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx2.buildContents(UIViewRootEx2.java:246)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createViewRoot(AbstractCompiledPage.java:167)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:511)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp</values>
        <values>.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:557)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:141)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:238)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:200)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:137)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1267)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(Compo</values>
        <values>nentModule.java:847)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1251)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:598)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:421)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)&#xD;&#xA;Caused by: com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.</values>
        <values>JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:132)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.getComputeWithForm(DominoDocumentData.java:206)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.doOpenDocument(DominoDocumentData.java:493)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;... 56 more&#xD;&#xA;Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject$ClassInfoCache.&lt;init&gt;(JavaAccessObject.java:1050)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.getClassInfoCache(JavaAccessObject.java:963)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.construct(JavaAccessObject.java:240)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaWrapperObject.construct(JavaWrapperObject.java:1)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTNew.interpret(ASTNew.java:109)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTVariableDecl.interpret(ASTVariableDecl.java:82)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTr</values>
        <values>ee.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:85)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:221)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInte</values>
        <values>rpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:193)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:78)&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;... 58 more&#xD;&#xA;</values>
    </extendedDataElements>
    <sourceComponentId component="Expeditor 6.2" componentIdType="ProductName" instanceId="" location="Christian-PC" locationType="Hostname" subComponent="" threadId="0" componentType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    <situation categoryName="ReportSituation">
        <situationType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ReportSituation" reasoningScope="INTERNAL" reportCategory="LOG"/>
    </situation>
</CommonBaseEvent>
```

Here's the readable stacktrace part:

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Could not open the document
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.doOpenDocument(DominoDocumentData.java:505)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDocumentDataSource.openDocument(AbstractDocumentDataSource.java:148)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDocumentDataSource.load(AbstractDocumentDataSource.java:100)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDataSource.getDataContainer(AbstractDataSource.java:474)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.getDataObject(DominoDocumentData.java:146)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.AbstractDataSource.pushData(AbstractDataSource.java:576)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.DataPublisher.publishControlData(DataPublisher.java:181)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.publishControlData(UIDataPanelBase.java:310)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.initBeforeContents(UIDataPanelBase.java:451)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.initBeforePageContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:668)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:339)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.addComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:389)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.buildContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:453)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildFacet(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:205)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UICallback.buildContents(UICallback.java:180)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.layout.UIVarPublisherBase.buildContents(UIVarPublisherBase.java:97)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.buildPageContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:692)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:340)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.addComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:389)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.buildContents(UIIncludeComposite.java:453)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:123)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(CompiledComponentBuilder.java:84)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.buildContents(UIViewRootEx.java:1649)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx2.buildContents(UIViewRootEx2.java:246)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(AbstractCompiledPage.java:334)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(AbstractCompiledPage.java:256)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createViewRoot(AbstractCompiledPage.java:167)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:511)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:557)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:141)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:238)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:200)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:137)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1267)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:847)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1251)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:598)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:421)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
    at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:132)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.getComputeWithForm(DominoDocumentData.java:206)
    at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.doOpenDocument(DominoDocumentData.java:493)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject$ClassInfoCache.<init>(JavaAccessObject.java:1050)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.getClassInfoCache(JavaAccessObject.java:963)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.construct(JavaAccessObject.java:240)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaWrapperObject.construct(JavaWrapperObject.java:1)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTNew.interpret(ASTNew.java:109)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTVariableDecl.interpret(ASTVariableDecl.java:82)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:85)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
    at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:221)
    at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:193)
    at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:78)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: If they should only be available in one app, what's the advantage of the JAR? Why not just include the source directly in the build path?

Comment: realy simple Java code is plaintext .class files are not so easy readable

Comment: In that case, store the source files on your local filesystem, and add the location to the build path as a linked source folder. At compile time, the classes will be stored in the NSF, but the actual source files are never stored in the application. That still doesn't prevent your code from being decompiled... if someone wants your source badly enough, they'll find it. But this makes it at least a bit more challenging to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a null value somewhere

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
 at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject$ClassInfoCache.(JavaAccessObject.java:1050)

And probably in an SSJS statement or within a java class called by SSJS

Caused by: com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
 at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript. JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:132)
 at com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData.getComputeWithForm(DominoDocumentData.java:206)

As for exporting your java source to a jar file. I assume you're working in eclipse. Right click the plugin in eclipse you're wanting to export and select "Export" and in the resulting dialog select "Plug-in Development\Deployable Plug-ins and Fragments". In the next dialog, select the path you want to export the plug-in to (presumably the %Domino_Program%\data\domino\workspace\applications\eclipse folder). Then do a "restart task http" (you must use this as it restarts the JVM also) and your plugin should be available to the server.

Since you're also developing components I assume you want those components available in designer. Since I'm not sure how you have designer setup (i.e. install via an update site or via a link directory that you place plugins in) I will need more information. If you're using the update site, use google to find how to build an update site from eclipse.

Comment: Hi Kieth thanks for response but this didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Hi Kieth thanks for response but this didn't solve my problem.
For exmaple: I create an Java file with a funktion that returns a simple XSPInputtext. pack this class in a jar file ( leftclick->export and s.o.)and use it in an JSf Control I get the same error. Are there some additional steps to export the jar file?
The problem by a plugin is: the controls should be available in one nsf not in the hole designer/Server. I would use a jar file because this controls are for customers to extend there nsf's. with a copy protection witch prevent itself by a replica id filter

Comment: I've never done this sort of thing so I'm afraid I can't help. If you're developing custom components that you want to re-use, sell or distribute then I highly recommend you use a plug-in. This makes things a lot easier to distribute. Take a look at the XSP Starter Kit on OpenNTF to get started with a custom plug-in.